# Unity3d cannot find Resources namespace

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using **2019.3.0f6** version of Unity. I purchased 3 plugin and they all give error after import.

I am getting error like this:

> Assets\PlayMaker\Editor\EditorStartupPrefs.cs(38,32): error CS0234:
>   The type or namespace name 'Load' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Resources' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What's the problem, I researched but not saw this error.

What I tried and not worked:

- **Help -> Reset Package to Defaults.**
- **Install 2018.4
  of Unity. Again throws error**

[image]

Comment: What type project are you using?  The Load implies a project that is a form or other project that loads an object.

Comment: @jdweng type is 2d. android.

Comment: What is your net version?

Comment: My version is  2019.3.0f6 (27ab2135bccf) Personal

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Some of script have Resources namespace. I deleted namespace and its solved.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess from this information, but could it be uncompatibily issues between the modules?
Check out this page: https://answers.unity.com/questions/316805/unityeditor-namespace-not-found.html

You can check that the target version of the purchased module is compatible with your editor version:
[image]

Check that during import the Assembly Info is compatible with your targeted framework version.

Comment: During import I cannot find screen like that. I thought that Playmaker not compatible with 2019.3.0f6 but not playmaker worked, also 2 plugins give that error... Also it is not DLL error.